# SELECT COUNT(*) насколько сильно грузит сервер? MySQL

Tags: mysql, оптимизация, select, count

На сайте доске объявлений много категорий и подкатегорий, ссылки на все на главной странице. Подсчет количества объявлений идет через SELECT COUNT(*) + условие. Получается что при открытии главной страницы выполняются десятки SELECT COUNT(*), как такое оптимизировать, сделать отдельную таблицу и считать скриптом периодически или еще есть какие методы?

Comment: как вариант - делаете триггер на добавление и удаление записей. и поддерживаете актуальный счетчик в другой таблице

Comment: Можно как то по колдовать с кэшем, и не обращаться к базе каждый раз.

Comment: Если все колонки используемые в условии включены в один индекс, то  скорее всего подсчет строк будет идти по индексу, не заглядывая в данные. Что можно увидеть в плане выполнения запроса по "using index" в поле Extra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count` для транзакционных СУБД (innodb в частности) вообще штука жуткая. Нужно выполнить запрос, найти все подходящие строки таблицы, поднять их все в память, проверить, видна ли эта строка в этой транзакции. Это ведь MVCC, строка может быть уже удалена в другой транзакции, а при update возможно одновременное существование нескольких разных версию одной строки - и надо выяснить, какая из них видна именно в этой транзакции.

Нетранзакционный `myisam` в переводе означает "мне эти данные не нужны, потеряются в случае чего и фиг с ними", поэтому о нём даже не говорю.

Теперь вопрос что с этим делать. Ответ зависит от того, что и насколько актуально надо получать. Я не вполне понял, почему у вас выполняются десятки разных count при окрытии страницы вместо одного аггрегированого. Так что возможно какая-то специфика.

- В общем виде задачу "а сколько у нас объявлений в категории" удобно решать пачкой триггеров. Заводится в отдельной табличке, или более часто в этой же таблице категорий, поле для числа объявлений в категории.  Триггер на insert в таблицу объявлений делает +1, триггер на delete - -1, триггер на update проверяет, изменился ли номер категории. Если изменился, соответственно, делает -1 старой категории и +1 новой. Счётчики "показывать до указанных даты и времени" становится так считать неудобно
- Если строгая актуальность счётчика не требуется, (для такой задачи она и не нужна обычно, ну будет целую минуту объявлений 232, а не 230 и ладно), то счётчики можно так же выкинуть в отдельную таблицу и считать планировщиком. У mysql, кстати, есть штатный event scheduler, на который эту задачу можно и повесить. Логика счётчиков в одном месте, а не в целой пачке триггеров, вполне нормально считаются объявления с ограничением по дате

Из часто используемых подходов всё. Можете сразу в коде делать +-1 при действиях с объявлениями, но это те же самые триггеры получаются.

Comment: А как быть когда при подсчете нужно учитывать большое разнообразие условий в where?